# LINQ join multi table

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have 4 tables:

```
table1
id1,
fk_tbl2 //this is the foreign key to the "id" in table2

table2
id2,
fk_tbl3 //this is the foreign key to the "id" in table3

table3
id3,
fk_tbl4 //this is the foreign key to the "id" in table4

table4
id4,
name
```

I want to make a multi table join, that when the user input "id4", i can get a list of record in "table1".

how to write the join in C#?
Thanks.

Comment: That depends... Do the objects for these tables have properties which reference one another?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.fk_tbl2 equals t2.id2
join t3 in table3 on t2.fk_tbl3 equals t3.id3
join t4 in table4 on t3.fk_tbl4 equals t4.id4
where t4.id4 == id
select t1
```