# In linq at a time how to join multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, linq

I know how to join in linq, but failed to get the desired output from a plain join and I need some advanced idea. My table structure is as bellow
[image]

my input and out set is as bellow

[image]

Base on those tables I want to write a linq query which gives me the required table result.

Is it possible in linq or I need to create a list and manually update it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297295/linq-join-multi-table

Comment: Awais Mahmood,thank for your reply,i know how to make join in linq,please see the required table complexity,how to arrange data