# Querying table through association using LINQ to SQL vb.net

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

I have 3 table

CustNameTbl

```
_________________
| ID | CustName |
| 1  | Jel Farm |
| 2  | TSL. TRD.|
| 3  | YAZAKI   |
| 4  | TAILIN   |
```

ItemNameTbl

```
_________________
| ID | ItemName |
| 1  |    HSC   |
| 2  |    Pad   |
| 3  |Partition |
| 4  | B002001  |
| 5  |Box for B3|
| 6  |High Speed|
```

ItemInfoTbl

```
__________________________________________________
| ID | CustId | ItemId |  Qty  | Price | Remarks |
| 1  |   1    |   1    |   50  |   2   |         |
| 2  |   1    |   2    |  200  |   1   |  Set A  |
| 3  |   1    |   3    |   10  |   5   |  Set B  |
| 4  |   4    |   5    |   15  |   2   |         |
| 5  |   4    |   6    |   10  |   1   |         |
| 6  |   2    |   4    |  150  |   3   |         |
```

I have two ASSOCIATION

1. CustNameTbl as Parent ItemInfoTbl as Child
2. ItemNameTbl as Parent ItemInfoTbl as Child

Using Linq to Sql, How to query ItemInfoTbl using CustNameTbl as WHERE CLAUSE and having a result where the value of CustId and ItemId in ItemInfoTbl will get there data in the other table (CustNameTbl,ItemNameTbl)

Like This:

```
____________________________________________________
| ID | CustId |  ItemId  |  Qty  | Price | Remarks |
| 4  | TAILIN |Box for B3|   15  |   2   |         |
| 5  | TAILIN |High Speed|   10  |   1   |         |
```

But my code didn't get what I want

```
Dim CustName As String = "TAILIN"
Using CustItem As New CustItemDataContext
        Dim resultCustItem = From result In CustItem.ItemInfoTbls
                             Where result.CustNameTbl.CustName = CustName
        DataGridView1.DataSource = resultCustItem
End Using
```

Any idea or link to get me started. Thank you, and sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not test but can give you an idea.

```
Dim result = from t in  YourDatabase.ItemInfoTbl
                        join p in YourDatabase.ItemNameTbl on t.ItemID equals p.ID 
                        join c in YourDatabase.CustNameTbl on t.CustID  equals c.ID            
Where c.CustName = CustName
                        select new
                        {
                            t.ID,
                            t.CustId,
                            t.ItemID,
                            t.Qty,
                            t.Price
                         };
```

Helpful source
[LINQ join multi table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17297295/linq-join-multi-table)

Comment: So that what JOIN can do. Thank you for the help.  I have read join before i just don't know how to use it.